# BlackBerry - prevent screen redraw while doing layout changes, then redraw all at once

Tags: user-interface, layout, blackberry

I have a few managers within managers (mostly VerticalFieldManagers) on a screen.

On an event, I need to change the layout of some managers on the screen. This includes adding/deleting fields to/from VerticalFieldManagers.

Ultimately there is quite a noticable flicker (currently testing on emulator & a Torch device) on this re-laying out.

I have a feeling I've read about a way to prevent the screen from redrawing, which would enable me to batch all the updates at once, and then just call 1 redraw. It might be something really simple, but I can't find it atm, & can not see any related questions here.

- What is the BB trick for doing changes like this to prevent /
  minimize screen flicker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suspend and resume screen painting by using [UiApplication.suspendPainting(boolean)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/UiApplication.html#suspendPainting%28boolean%29) with the parameter being `true` to suspend, and `false` to resume.

Comment: @jproffit: I knew it was something simple like that, but just couldn't remember where I had read it. Thx